# How to remove <pre> tag

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a pre tag which is causing the css to display with too much whitespace.
How do I remove it with css?

```
        <!-- page-title -->

            <h1 class="page-title" itemprop="name">Checkout</h1>

        <!-- /page-title -->

        <div class="page-content entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">

        **<pre>**<div class="woocommerce">
       <div class="woocommerce-info">Have a coupon? <a href="#" class="showcoupon">Click here to       enter your code</a></div>

     <form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">
```

The css reads

```
pre, xmp, plaintext, listing {
display: block;
font-family: monospace;
white-space: pre;
margin: 1em 0px;
}
```

how do I change whitespace:pre? 
This is a wordpress site using woocommerce plugin.

Comment: The whole point of `<pre>` is to have that whitespace. Why not remove the actual tag itself if you don't want it? Is this in the theme?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove <pre> tag from woocommerce checkout page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124650/remove-pre-tag-from-woocommerce-checkout-page)

Comment: The proposed duplicate (i) does not have answers (ii) already nominated for closure.

Comment: I can't find the <pre> tag in the theme. It is a using the woocommerce plugin, checkout page. It shouldn't have this tag I don't understand why it is showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following to your CSS to overwrite this specific pre tag

```
.page-content.entry-content pre {
white-space: normal;
}
```

If you use a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), you can add it in your stylesheet (style.css), else you could use [Jetpack's Custom CSS](http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/) to add it.

If the above wouldn't work, try:

```
.page-content.entry-content pre {
white-space: normal !important;
}
```

GL!

Comment: I can't make any css changes with pre work. If I try in 'inspect element' the pre goes a light grey and is not used on the page.

Comment: Via inspect element, when the element you add to the CSS turns grey, it means it has no effect on the currently selected code. So, when you select the pre to the right and you add a style for it, and it turns grey, you probably made an error in the name. Did you copy the name, or type it? Make sure you do not have a space between '.page-content' and '.entry-content'.